# What is the Go equivalent of Scala SHA512 hash?

Tags: scala, go, hash, cryptography, sha512

In `Scala` we have a part of code that hash a string in SHA512 and then pad the string in `Hexadecimal` format:

```
String.format("%032x", new BigInteger(1, MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512").digest("MyStringToBeHashed".getBytes("UTF-8"))))
```

I hash string in Go using crypto package:

```
package main

import (
        "crypto/sha512"
        "encoding/base64"
)

func main() {
        hasher := sha512.New()
        hasher.Write([]byte("MyStringToBeHashed"))
        sha := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
        sha = fmt.Sprintf("%032x", sha)
        println(sha)
}
```

In `Scala` I get the below output:

```
b0bcb1263862e574e5c9bcb88a3a14884625613410bac4f0be3e3b601a6dee78f5635d0f7b6eb19ba5a1d80142d9ff2678946331874c998226b16e7ff48e53e5
```

But in `Go`:

```
734c79784a6a68693558546c79627934696a6f556945596c5954515175735477766a343759427074376e6a3159313050653236786d365768324146433266386d654a526a4d59644d6d59496d7357355f3949355435513d3d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The additional base64 encoding is wrong. You either want to show the hash as base64 (i.e. `base64(hash)`) or you want to show the hash as hex string (i.e. `hex(hash)`) - but what you do instead is to show the base64 encoded hash as hex string (i.e. `hex(base64(hash))`). Simply do instead:

```
    sha := fmt.Sprintf("%032x", hasher.Sum(nil))
```

Comment: alternatively `hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))` with imported encoding/hex